# Save Image view

Tags: android, imageview

Can someone help me understand how to use `OnPause()` and `OnResume()` in this code? I'm trying to save last Selected or Captured image in imageView so when the user closes the program and comes back again he doesn't  need to set or take the image again.

```
package com.example.thang.sdcardimagesactivity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private Bitmap bitmap;
Button button;
ImageView imageView;
String selectedImagePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
    imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Switch();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
public void Switch(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==REQUEST_CODE&&resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
        try{
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Log.v("roni", filePath);
            cursor.close();
            if(bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled())
            {
                bitmap = null;
            }
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            //imageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 1); // Open SharedPreferences with name AppSharedPref
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("ImagePath", selectedImagePath); // Store selectedImagePath with key "ImagePath". This key will be then used to retrieve data.
    editor.commit();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPref", 1);
    selectedImagePath = sp.getString("ImagePath", "");
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    super.onResume();
}
}

View Activity


public class ViewActivity extends Activity {
ImageButton imageViews;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    imageViews = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image);
    //   textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

    if (intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1)
    {
        imageViews.setImageURI(data);
    }
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("image",R.id.image);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    finish();
}
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to select image multiple from camera and devices gallery ?

Comment: Can't understand your way. Are you want to capture image on click of imageview? and want to set captured image as src of imageview?

Answer (score 0):

You can save an image to the SD card so it can be permanently accessed. It's best you do this immediately in the onActivityResult() method.

```
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImagesFolder");
File file = new File(imagesFolder, "image.jpg");
String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    squareBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Image", "Convert");
}
```

And to load it back when you restart the application (in onCreate or preferably in onResume):

```
try {
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ImagesFolder");
    if (!imagesFolder.exists())
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();
    if (new File(imagesFolder, "image.jpg").exists()) {
        String fileName = new File(imagesFolder, "image.jpg").getAbsolutePath();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "null");
}
```

Of course you can change the folder and image name.